# Custom sort of map by key

Tags: java, java-8

We have an Object  key  to a map  - `Map<Student,List<Subject>>:`

```
class Student {
  String admitDate; //20190702
  String name;
  .....
}
```

At a particular trigger, we would like to sort the map based on the admitdate(in Date) of the Student - and remove the earliest admit/s.
The equals and hashcode of Student have a different comparison  - so it cannot be a generic sort.
We are on Java 8.
What would be the least code way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: if your `equals` and `hashcode` implementations are incompatible, your class is broken. Be aware that you can never safely use it in any Collections using hashes, i.e. HashMaps/Sets.

Comment: There is not just one solution, but in general “sorting a map” is not possible. You may look into using a `TreeMap`. It’s always sorted, and you may give it a comparator to specify how it should be sorted.

Comment: Hulk, my interpretation is that they are not broken but they are not solely based on admit date so they can't be used for comparison. I think the purpose of this problem is to make students write a custom Comparator.

Comment: define "most efficient"? (less code, easy code, time, ...);  and what is the context? (number of entries, range of values, ....)

Comment: @Hulk , what do you mean by *your class is broken*?

Comment: I onyl meant that *if* your `equals` and `hashcode` are not compatible with each other, then the class breaks the contract defined by `Object`. I may have misunderstood your statement about them "having a different comparison", sorry about any confusion caused by that. If you merely need a custom ordering, I agree that a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` is the way to go.

Comment: First of all, tell me whether you're using a `HashMap<>` or `LinkedHashMap<>`?

Comment: ...at least if you always want to sort/filter that way. See for example also [TreeMap.subMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-) for getting only the mappings between specific keys. If you need to sort for different fields in different situations, however, it might be easier to just keep them in whatever Map you like, and sort/filter them when needed.

Comment: [Veggiebob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11749330/veggiebob) would like to say: Try converting the map into an array using keys and then sorting the array instead; in my experience with maps in Javascript it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two things:

1. Custom comparator
2. `Map` implementation that supports sorting - `TreeMap`.

See snippet below:

```
// this is comparator that sorte `Student` accorgind to their `adminDate` ascending order
Comparator<Student> sortByAdminDateAsc = Comparator.comparingInt(one -> Integer.parseInt(one.adminDate));

// Use `TreeMap` with given comparator
Map<Student, List<Subject>> studentSubjects = new TreeMap<>(sortByAdminDateAsc);
// fill the map

studentSubjects.forEach((student, subjects) -> {
    // student are sorted according to comparator
});
```

In case you already have `HashMap`, then you can do smth. like this:

```
Map<Student, List<Subject>> studentSubjects = new HashMap<>();
Set<Student> sortedKeys = studentSubjects.keySet().stream().sorted(sortByAdminDateAsc).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Important:** using an approach with a custom comparator you are not depending on the internal implementation of Student's equals and hash code. Moreover, you can use as many comparators as you can for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace String with Student and Integer with List from below code

```
private static void sortBasedOnKey(Map<String, Integer> input) {

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list= new ArrayList<>(input.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getKey().compareTo(obj2.getKey()));
    Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    list.forEach(obj -> resultMap.put(obj.getKey(), obj.getValue()));
    System.out.println(resultMap);
}
```